# Standard Login Page | Change Button and Link Color

Tags: lightning, mydomain

I've turned on "My Domain" but am unable to change the color of the login button or "Forgot Your Password?" link. I don't see anything available in the My Domain screen. The settings for My Domain show the same in Lightning as in Classic. I went into the Developer Console and tried looking for something. Things like "loginForm.css" and "selfRegister.css" don't change the page.

Does anyone know where the page is, so that some colors settings could be changed?

[image: My Domain Login]
[image: My Domain Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lightning Standard Login page only Background color, Logo image & a wallpaper can be added.

There is no option to change color of login buttons & links.

What you want can be done for custom community login page.